# Can I use Apple Pay to create a Stripe Token without charging the user?

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, applepay

I'm making an app where I need to collect user credit card info at some point so I can charge them later. Right now I use stripe and their PTKView to collect credit card info and store it. Then later on when the user wants to pay I'm ready to go and they don't have to do anything else. I would like to add the option for a user to import a card from Apple Pay that I could then use later on. However, it seems to me that when using Apple Pay I have to charge the user right then. I am curious if anyone knows a solution for this problem or if I just have to create a "Pay with Apple Pay" option on the last screen before the user pays. This would not be preferable but currently it looks to be my only choice.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27775602/create-token-with-apple-pay-without-payment) post, which is unfortunately unanswered. However, question #1 is exactly what I am asking. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create an Apple Pay payment option that is equivalent to your in-house payment option wherever the user decides how the transaction will be processed. Do note though that creating the token and processing the payment are separated operations, though it's unlikely you'll do one without the other in normal circumstances.

This is true not just for the code but for compliance with Apple's Apple Pay Identity Guidelines: https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/Apple-Pay-Identity-Guidelines.pdf -- Read the whole thing, but see p11 particularly (in the Dec-2014 version anyway, the discussion of the Apple Pay Payment Mark).

Comment: Agree that this is enormously obnoxious (surprise surprise, thanks Apple). You cannot prompt the user for credit card/ApplePay payment authorization without charging them (or at least making it look like you intend to charge them). So much for, say, subscriptions, or collecting credit card info the way Uber and a thousand other apps do so that you can charge the user for future purchases. You have to either 1. not use Apple Pay, or 2. "charge" the user $0.01 and make it clear you're not actually charging them (unclear whether this violates Apple's terms).